# The order column in Azure boards

Tags: azure-devops, azure-boards

I am using Azure DevOps boards and when I navigate to Backlogs in Azure Boards, I see a column named Order.

[image]

When I check/open the work items, they don't have a field named "order". There is no value seen for that column for us. We are not sure whats the purpose of such field/column and where we can enter the values for it.

Kindly share your information on this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This column represents a sequence of your work. The mapped work item field depends on your team project process template: [Backlog priority or stack rank order](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/backlogs/backlogs-overview?view=azure-devops#backlog-priority-or-stack-rank-order)

> As you drag and drop items within the backlog list, a background
> process updates the Stack Rank (Agile and CMMI processes) or Backlog
> Priority (Scrum process) fields

Additionally, the backlogs do not show the order if you enable parents in the view.

Helpful link: [Fix display, reordering, and nesting issues](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/backlogs/resolve-backlog-reorder-issues?view=azure-devops)